# T-SQL: Problems with dynamic variable in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to store the result of the following select into a variable.

```
SET @SearchSchema = '(SELECT REPLACE(name,''Change Log Setup'', ''Change Log Entry'') as Name  FROM ['+@DBName+'].sys.tables where name LIKE ''%$Change Log Setup'')'
```

I tried also with exec sp_executesql.

Here is the whole code:

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @period VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @SQLEXE VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @SearchSchema NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @Authentification VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @ServerName VARCHAR(1000);

SET @period = '''2017-01-01 00:00:00'' AND ''2017-12-31 23:59:59''';    
SET @Path = 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\';                                   
SET @Servername = '-S nav-ey-demo2\NAVDEMO';

SET @DBName = (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name LIKE '%NAV%');
EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName+']'); Select db_name();

SET @SearchSchema = '(SELECT REPLACE(name,''Change Log Setup'', ''Change Log Entry'') as Name  FROM ['+@DBName+'].sys.tables where name LIKE ''%$Change Log Setup'')'
```

If I use

```
SELECT @SearchSchema
```

the correct value is appears.

By using

```
PRINT '@SEARCHSCHEMA ' + @SearchSchema
```

the SELECT string is displayed:

```
SEARCHSCHEMA (SELECT REPLACE(name,'Change Log Setup', 'Change Log Entry') as Name  FROM [Demo Database NAV (10-0)].sys.tables where name LIKE '%$Change Log Setup')
```

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: I want to store a SELECT result into a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to construct your dynamic query, then you execute it calling `sp_executesql` and then store the result to a variable.

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @period VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @SQLEXE VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @SearchSchema NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @Authentification VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @ServerName VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @QueryResult NVARCHAR(4000); 

SET @period = '''2017-01-01 00:00:00'' AND ''2017-12-31 23:59:59''';    --DON'T change the audit period. It is only allowed by the EY auditor. A change of this value can be easily detected.
SET @Path = 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\';                                   --you can change the path directory
SET @Servername = '-S nav-ey-demo2\NAVDEMO';

SET @DBName = (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name LIKE '%NAV%');
EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName+']'); Select db_name();

SET @SearchSchema = '(SELECT @ResultOut = REPLACE(name,''Change Log Setup'', ''Change Log Entry'') as Name  FROM ['+@DBName+'].sys.tables where name LIKE ''%$Change Log Setup'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SearchSchema, '@ResultOut NVARCHAR(4000) OUTPUT', @ResultOut=@QueryResult OUTPUT;

SELECT @QueryResult;
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work because using a variable for an object name requires dynamic sql.

Comment: @TabAlleman you are correct..i missed the FROM ['+@DBName+'] part...i have updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunatly ...it does not work....
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: @WIbadeneralp try change the declaration of DBName to NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR and let me know if that works.

Comment: no, error message
Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar

I tried to convert the parameters but it didn't work.

Comment: N was missing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024394/procedure-expects-parameter-params-of-type-ntext-nchar-nvarchar